# How to get views from fragments in onClick

Tags: android, android-fragments, view, onclick

I have an activity with a String array and a Drawable array. I create fragments using a for loop in the onCreate according to the length of the arrays and use the String array to fill TextViews in the fragments.

I made the fragments clickable and added onClick in the fragment class.

I want to get the text from the fragment the user clicks, but when I click it only gets the text from the first fragment. How can I read the textviews in the different fragments.

```
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        int layoutId = getArguments().getInt("layout");
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(layoutId, container, false);
        TextView fragmentText = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.fragTextView);
        fragmentText.setText(getArguments().getString("fragText"));
        ImageView fragmentImage = (ImageView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.fragImageView);
        fragmentImage.setImageResource(getArguments().getInt("pic"));
        rootView.setOnClickListener(this);
        return rootView;
    }
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            String s = ((TextView)v.getRootView().findViewById(R.id.fragTextView)).getText().toString();
            Intent intent = new Intent(v.getContext(), LevelActivity.class);
            intent.putExtra("exerciseId", s);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
```

Thanks

Comment: instead of `v.getRootView().` you can use `getView()`

Comment: For anyone wondering: getRootView returns the top most view in the hierarchy. That's why I was always getting the first TextView I filled.

Comment: if you feel like it could help somebody, post your comment as answer and mark it as *accepted answer*